# Access to elements of [<HDF5 object reference>]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5

I have a h5py file, which I read it this way:

```
a_file_train = h5py.File(clip_dir_yang_train, "r")
print(a_file_train.keys())
```

answer:

```
<KeysViewHDF5 ['#refs#', 'label', 'vec']>
```

Then for example, I run:

```
refs_file_1 = a_file_train.get('label')
```

And the result is:

```
<HDF5 dataset "label": shape (512, 1200), type "<f4">
```

I want to have access to inside of refs_file_1 elements, convert them to numpy arrays and do numerical calculations. However, I couldn't find a way. For example, I tried:

```
for item in refs_file_1:
    print(item)
```

And the result is:

```
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
[<HDF5 object reference>]
....
```

How can I have access to elements of refs_file_1?

Comment: In one line: ```labels = a_file_train['label'][:]```. A file (or group within a file) acts like a dictionary of groups and datasets. A dataset acts like a proxy for a numpy array. Just use normal array indexing as you would with a numpy array. Each access reads a slice of the dataset and gives you a normal numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, only the start of an answer to understand your question and determine your H5 file schema. Something in your question doesn't make sense. (It could be a copy/paste error, or it could be more complicated.)
After you entered:

```
refs_file_1 = a_file_train.get('label')
```

You get this output:

```
<HDF5 dataset "vec": shape (512, 1200), type "<f4">
```

Notice how it says `dataset "vec"` and not `dataset "label"`?
I would expect to see the output below. (I used `????` because I can't guess the shape and dtype of `dataset "label"`.)

```
<HDF5 dataset "label": shape (????), type <"????">
```

Use this to interrogate all 3 top level objects (assumes all are datasets):

```
with h5py.File(clip_dir_yang_train, "r") as a_file_train:
    for ds in a_file_train.keys():
        if isinstance(a_file_train[ds], h5py.Group): 
            print(f"{ds} is a Group")        
        elif isinstance(a_file_train[ds], h5py.Dataset): 
            print(f"{ds} is a Dataset")   
            print(f"shape: {a_file_train[ds].shape}; dtype: {a_file_train[ds].dtype}")
        else:
            print(f"{ds} is not a Group or Dataset")
```

Your update confirms the `'label'` dataset is an array of HDF5 object references. An object reference points to another object (typically another dataset) in the file. This is common with files created by MATLAB. Accessing object references is slightly more complicated than reading a dataset as an array of floats or ints. So, you have to do a little more work. First you have to de-reference the object reference, then use it to read the data. Not hard, just more involved.

This shows a way to use the object references from the `'label'` dataset then use them to read the referenced datasets. Warning, you have a lot of object references  `(512, 1200)`, and this will print all of them. So, you may want to modify it to only read a few objects.

```
with h5py.File(clip_dir_yang_train, "r") as a_file_train:
    # create a h5py dataset object (can be used like a np.array)
    refs_file_1 = a_file_train['label']
    # loop over each item in the label dataset (object references):
    for item in refs_file_1:
        # 2 statements below assume all referenced objects are datasets:
        print(a_file_train[item])   # prints info about referenced dataset
        print(a_file_train[item][:]) # prints values in referenced dataset
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
The problem in the question was a copy/paste mistake. I edited the question.

I tried running the code you kindly wrote, however, the result was like this:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-001212a7d980> in <module>
      1 with h5py.File(clip_dir_yang_train, "r") as a_file_train:
      2     for ds in a_file_train.keys():
----> 3         print(f"For Dataset name: {ds}; shape: {a_file_train[ds].shape}; dtype: {a_file_train[ds].dtype}")

AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Ah, ok, 1 or more of your root level objects (keys) is a group. I suspect the group holds the datasets that are referenced by the object references. I will modify my code snippet to test for groups vs datasets. Also, now that you confirmed the dataset/key name, I will add the code to read the object reference and use it to read the referenced dataset.